# Why am I getting an Xcode build error from lex "gm4:stdin:1744: ERROR: end of file in string"

Tags: xcode, build, lex

Building a [github .xcodeproject](https://github.com/nickzman/ManOpen) and running into the same error for two forks of manOpen. I am having trouble understanding what the issue is.

I am  new to building using Xcode so figure this must be simply a "new user mistake".

I cloned the project into /usr/local/Projects

When I build I get this error:

```
Lex /usr/local/Projects/ManOpen/ManOpen/cat2html.tproj/cat2html.l (in target 'cat2html (Tool)' from project 'ManOpen')
    cd /usr/local/Projects/ManOpen
    export DEVELOPER_DIR\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lex -o /Users/john/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ManOpen-bztxjqkaqtyazxhiudyipgfevout/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ManOpen.build/Debug/cat2html\ \(Tool\).build/DerivedSources/cat2html.yy.c /usr/local/Projects/ManOpen/ManOpen/cat2html.tproj/cat2html.l

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/gm4:stdin:1744: ERROR: end of file in string
Command Lex failed with a nonzero exit code
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a fix, but a work-around: ManOpen Uses cat2rtf as of Mac OS 10.4, so you can remove cat2html as a dependency of ManOpen.